# Passing Dictionary in a specific order or keys in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

First of all, i am aware of how to perform sorting function on a dictionary key values and also i can fetch the values of the key by using another Key array for order reference.

I have the following `NSDictionary`

```
NSMutableDictionary *postData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[postData setObject:txtFieldFullName.text forKey:@"FullName"];

[postData setObject:txtFieldCountry.text forKey:@"CountryName"];

[postData setObject:countryCode forKey:@"CountryCode"];

[postData setObject:txtFieldMobileNumber.text forKey:@"MobileNumber"];
```

The problem I am facing is that I have to pass this dictionary to the API server in the exact key order mentioned above. is there any way?

Comment: It will help people help you if you edit your question and show how you are passing the dictionary to the API server. Otherwise people can only guess or give the the simple but unhelpful answer of "yes" (as you "just" need to write the code). HTH

Comment: If you are going to use NSJSONSerialization then the result is non ordered. So, you have to use custom ordered dictionary with a custom JSON serialization class